# Using HttpClient To Login To https://id.wsj.com/access/50f57264bd7fb2d2f6629af6/latest/login_standalone.html

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

guys am trying to login to the URL `https://id.wsj.com/access/50f57264bd7fb2d2f6629af6/latest/login_standalone.html` using HttpClient. But the client does not load the css from http://a248.e.akamai.net:443 when calling via code. I debugged the code using `Fiddler`.

My code :

```
public void getRequest() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    try {
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setProxy(proxy).setUserAgent("").build();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        try {
            BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
            localContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost("id.wsj.com", 443, "https");
            HttpGet req = new HttpGet("/access/50f57264bd7fb2d2f6629af6/latest/login_standalone.html");
            req.addHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            req.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36");

            System.out.println("executing request to " + target + " via " + proxy);
            HttpResponse rsp = httpclient.execute(target, req, localContext);
            System.out.println("Status Code" + rsp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            printHeaders(rsp.getAllHeaders());
            printCookies(cookieStore);

        } finally {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Fiddler Snapshot via Java

http://s3.postimg.org/qimqrxo2q/using_httpclient.jpg

Snapshot via chrome

http://s17.postimg.org/u6dpmvuam/via_chrome.jpg

Am new to this, so please help experts! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IMO - you are grabbing an html page you may not need to logon. Assume there is not an API ( official logon call for WSJ - like the api logon you see [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-login) ).

You should use your debug tools in order to see what gets POST'd when you click the 'Login' button on WSJ. You are dealing with a page that is too early in the process. To logon programmatically, why is it relevant what is in the page that formats a dialog ( rather than processes ) involved with "onLogonRequested" event on the logon page? Focus on what the page and the JS send to the WSJ server over XHR when the logon button is clicked. Then use your HTTP client to format a POST that is as close as you can clone to the XHR POST mention above.

You may also need to address the 'session' variable between the path nodes 'access' and 'latest'. If that is just cookie info, you may be able to ignore it. Again, its mixed up with a page dialog and not an api for logging on.

That may get you logged in.

Comment: before everything i tried what you said. I used the `jquery` serialize function on the submit form to see what all parameters are being used for POST request. But it failed. I captured the response and saw that the login form was not loaded completely and the submit button was disabled as The css was not loaded from the `akamai` server. Since then am trying to first load the whole page properly!

Comment: Use another WIRE level analyzer. You MUST know exactly whats in the POST. If your jquery tools don't cut it then find another tool.. try wireshark. You are in the dark until you establish what's being POST'd. What are the headers? What is in the post body?

Comment: I analysed it using `Fiddler`! The code doesnt load the css which Google Chrome does from the server and proper page is displayed! `I BLOCKED THE AKAMAI DOMAIN ON MY MACHINE ONCE AND THE SAME PAGE (PAGE WHICH HAS SUBMIT BUTTON DISABLED) IS LOADED BY THE Google Chrome AS BY THE SCRIPT (CAPTURED THE POST HIT RESPONSE )!` and hence UNABLE TO LOGIN :(